# Apache Upgrade Version

Tags: apache-2.2, windows-server-2003, httpd.conf

I have a live server that I need to upgrade Apache from 2.2.10 to 2.2.15
 on Windows Server 2003.

I have just inherited this server and need the fastest way to upgrade to the latest stable version without much downtime and without messing up my configuration.

My first thought is to copy the httpd.conf, uninstall the current Apache, install the latest stable Apache version and then replace the httpd.conf with the previous live version.

Anyone see a problem or pitfall with that?

How does a Server Pro do something like this. (I'm a programmer and am new to server systems administration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what I'd do on Unix, although the configuration doesn't get replaced - it's only the binaries that get replaced.

On Unix you can get away with a simple restart of the web services to get the upgraded version running, you'll probably find it's the same on Windows.

Just make sure you have a copy of the entire conf directory (not just httpd.conf as there are other files that could be referenced.)

If I were you, I'd also copy the entire Apache installation directory, that way if things go pear-shaped you can just replace the binary files and restart the services to get it back up and running - then diagnose what went wrong.

Every point release of Apache I've done has been text-book though, so I wouldn't expect any issues.